# Как зделать когда при добавлении бота на сервер выдавалась роль discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Здраствуйте хотел бы задать такой вопрос.
Как при добавлении бота на сервер создавалась роль например Muted
И что для этого надо?**

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример кода для эвента захода на сервер и создавания роли.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(
            mutedRole,
            speak=False,
            send_messages=False,
            read_message_history=True,
            read_messages=False,
        )
```